# How much current the PS-on pin on the motherboard's power connector can sink?

Tags: atx, motherboard, pc

How much current the PS-on pin on the motherboard's power connector can sink? 
can it sink 100-200mA?

(to activate a relay/solid-state-relay when the motherboard wants to turn/keep on the computer)
(e.g. motherboard's PS-on pin >>> relay/solid-state-relay >>> my controller board >>> computer's PSU's PS-on wire)

Comment: There is a separate standby wire you can use for some power before the main power rails turn on. In the worst case you can use that to drive the solid state relay after buffering the PS-on signal.

Comment: Right; but I wanted to know is it really necessary to buffer the PS-on signal or i can use it directly to drive a solid-state relay.

Comment: Either Im reading this wrong, or there seems to be some confusion. PWR_ON (green wire) is pulled to 5v internally via large value resistor, when pulled <0.8v (or directly to gnd) the PSU activates the voltage rails. PWR_OK (grey) signals the mobo the rails have stabilized (with +5v). STB (purple) provides 5vdc (at only an amp or two) for standby circuitry. STB to power a MCU which grounds PWR_ON and confirms with PWR_OK would be the 'correct' method. STB is the only one designed to supply current, but PWR_OK can power an LED so should be able to trip a transistor, or darlington for feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [ATX Power Supply Design Guide, Verizon 2.01](http://www.formfactors.org/developer/specs/atx12v%20psdg2.01.pdf), page 24, the power supply is only allowed to draw 1.6mA. Based on that, it is very unlikely that any standard motherboard will sink 100mA.

Comment: I contacted gigabyte's support, and they confirmed that this pin can't sink 100-200mA.